# Positioned Widget Animation with Flutter

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

I have the following code in place to animate a `Positioned` widgets, position, when a pan ends. However, it doesn't animate.

Initialising `AnimationController` and variables:

```
  AnimationController nodesListAnimationController;
  Animation<double> nodesListAnimation;

  double nodesListOffsetY = 0.0; //widget default offset (will be large, but acts like 0.0)
  double nodesListDragOffsetY = 0.0; //how far we have moved the widget from default offset (nodesListOffsetY)
  double nodesListTouchOffset = 0.0; //the initial touch when drag begins
  final double nodesListHeight = 350.0; //widget height

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    nodesListAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    )
    ..addListener((){
      setState(() {

      });
    });

  }
```

Build function; See the `Positioned` widget. I can drag this up and down within the bound I have created using the panning callbacks on `GestureDetector`.

When the pan ends, I want to animate the `Positioned` widget back to a given position. Currently, no animation occurs.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    nodesListOffsetY = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width + 110.0;

    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      ...
    );

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                cameraWidget(),
                cameraControls(),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0.0,
              top: nodesListAnimationController.isAnimating ? nodesListAnimation.value : nodesListOffsetY + nodesListDragOffsetY,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: nodesListHeight,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanStart: (dragDetails) {
                  nodesListTouchOffset = (dragDetails.globalPosition.dy - appBar.preferredSize.height) - nodesListOffsetY - nodesListDragOffsetY;
                },
                onPanUpdate: (dragDetails) {
                  setState(() {
                    double newDragOffset = (dragDetails.globalPosition.dy - nodesListOffsetY) - appBar.preferredSize.height - nodesListTouchOffset;

                    //allow it only to move up if is clips off screen, otherwise upper limit not needed
                    double nodesListVisible = ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - appBar.preferredSize.height) - nodesListOffsetY);
                    bool isClipping = nodesListVisible < nodesListHeight ? true : false;
                    double upperLimit = 0.0;
                    if (isClipping) upperLimit = -(nodesListHeight - nodesListVisible);

                    //limit drag bounds. don't drag too high or low.
                    if (newDragOffset < upperLimit) newDragOffset = upperLimit;
                    else if (newDragOffset > 0) newDragOffset = 0.0;
                    else nodesListDragOffsetY = newDragOffset;
                  });
                },
                onPanEnd: (dragDetails) {
                  double currentPos = (nodesListOffsetY + nodesListDragOffsetY);
                  nodesListAnimation = Tween(begin: currentPos, end: nodesListOffsetY).animate(nodesListAnimationController);
                  nodesListAnimationController.forward(from: currentPos);
                  nodesListAnimation.addStatusListener((state) {
                    print(nodesListAnimation.value);
                  });
                },
                child: nodesList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Is your widget using an appropriate animation mixin?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? The only relation the widget has to the animation is the `top` value references the animation value in order to update the position.

Comment: Sorry, that was a little unclear. I meant the parent widget class that all of this code resides in (but I'm assuming it must be since you have your `vsync: this` argument inside of the AnimationController constructor.

Comment: Ahh, state function (stageful widget) includes `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: We have a shared aim of brevity and readability here, based somewhat on the idea that Stack Overflow is closer to Wikipedia or technical documentation than a chat-room. I note that you have 151 `help appreciated`s, and 57 `hope you can helps`, and I wonder if there is more editing work besides. Thus, if you can refrain from adding further to the pile, that is appreciated - we don't have enough editors on the site as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but your issue is because of:

```
nodesListAnimationController.forward(from: currentPos)
```

Whose `from` is incorrectly accepting a value outside of *0.0-1.0*. So you should probably change it to just `controller.forward()`

This isn’t well documented, but forward’s `from` is meant to accept values from *0.0-1.0*, or more specifically, if set, then the range provided by `lowerBound` and `upperBound` (with few exceptions). (*you can also think of it as 0-100%*). It is not meant to accept the value range from the Tween’s `begin` and `end`, nor is it aware of that range.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html

> By default, an AnimationController linearly produces values that range from 0.0 to 1.0

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/overview#addstatuslistener

> An animation might then run forward (e.g., from 0.0 to 1.0)

*(And I can verify that after I changed your code to use just `.forward()`, I was able to see it animate)*